# Error in grammar/distribution of votes

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes

Recently, I came across an incident in which I flagged a question as it was unclear. But, the message reads: Put on hold as unclear what you are asking. Even, I suffered a deduction of 2 votes. When I didn't post the question, why is Physics SE specifically targetting me?

Link to the question:

[What is the coefficient of volume expansion for ideal gases?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/495937/)

Comment: Hi Shishir. [Looking at your rep page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/234064/shishir-maharana?tab=reputation) I can't see any reputation loss yesterday.

Comment: @JohnRennie But I suffered a loss of 2 votes from 360 down to 358. How did it occur?

Comment: Also, it was written "Put on hold as unclear what you are asking". I didn't even ask that question, so why are they referring to me as 'you'?

Comment: Did you downvote a couple of questions? Each downvote costs you one rep point.

Comment: @JohnRennie Only downvotes on answers cost a rep point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[That question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/495937/2451) seems to be a red herring. The yellow on-hold message text is primarily meant for the original poster (OP), not you.

The deduction of 2 points from [your reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/234064/shishir-maharana?tab=reputation) is caused by something else. For example, a [suggested-edit](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/266326) gain of 2 reputation point was later removed again when the [edited post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/489185/2451) was deleted on August 3rd, 2019. (Deleted posts require 10k reputation to view.)